# Async function stops working when expecting result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which looks like this:

```
function myAsyncFunction(num){
   if(num>10){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

I then call this function asynchronously:

```
myAsyncFunction(100, function(result){

   console.log('The result is = ' + result); //this never gets called

});
```

But the console.log statement never gets printed. It should print either true or false.

Comment: You never call the function. You don't even define the argument. A function is not magically async...

Comment: The function you've shown us isn't asynchronous. And doesn't even take a callback.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. Don't I define the function is the first piece of code and then call it in the second piece of code?

Comment: @user2924127: elclanrs means that you're never calling the callback function you are passing to the `myAsyncFunction` call

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it correctly. You can pass the callback and call the callback with result as follows

```
function myAsyncFunction(num, callback){
   if(num > 10){
      callback(true);
   }else{
      callback(false);
   }
}

myAsyncFunction(100, function(result){
   console.log('The result is = ' + result); //this never gets called
});
```

Comment: FYI, this is still not asynchronous, so there's really no reason to do it this way with a callback rather than just return the result directly.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree that this doesn't need to do this way, as there is no blocking code. I just pointed out that the way OP's calling the function, there is need of callback :).

Answer (score 0):

Eg:Calling a JavaScript function "Asynchronously"

```
 function async(fn, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        fn();
        callback();
      }, 0);
    }

function sync(fn) {
    fn();
 }

function foo(){
  console.log('foo');
 }

console.log('SYNC TEST --------------');
//synchronous
console.log('start sync');
sync(foo);
console.log('end sync');
console.log('');

console.log('ASYNC TEST --------------');
//asynchronous
console.log('start async');
async(foo, function(){ 
    console.log('async callback');
});
console.log('end async');
```

### output

```
SYNC TEST --------------
start sync
foo
end sync

ASYNC TEST --------------
start async
end async
foo
async callback
```

Comment: This schedules the code to run at a future time, but when it runs, it still runs synchronously and blocks other code from running while it's doing its thing.  So, it's a bit of a stretch to call this async.  This is just scheduling it to run at a point in the future.

Comment: @jfriend00 and that's why it's called "asynchronous" and not "parallel". Asynchronous code *may* block, just by definition of the term.

Comment: @zerkms - The general point of async code in node.js is so that it can run in parallel to other things and be non-blocking and that is the common use of the term and async coding in node.js (despite any formal definition).  This code is not accomplishing the kind of async structure in node.js that prevents one operation from blocking the execution of other operations.  That's my point.  If you go back to the OP's question, it appears the OP is trying to make a synchronous, blocking operation, somehow magically become async, non-blocking.

Comment: @jfriend00 every asynchronous operation is non-blocking by definition. It's really important to be consistent in terms use so that everyone was on the same wave. To summarise: the code from this answer is non-blocking and asynchronous, by definition of the terms. To me it's not obvious if OP wants their code to run in parallel or not, it just lacks any traces to support either of the assumptions.

Comment: @zerkms - The one in this answer blocks node.js from doing other things "when it runs".  Something like async I/O in node.js does not block when it runs.  Huge difference - one should not confuse the two or think they are getting one when they have the other.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're confusing what "non-blocking", "asynchronous" and "parallel" terms mean. The code in this answer is non-blocking and asynchronous. What you want to express is called "parallel".

Comment: I repeat what I said.  When the code actually runs in the future, that will block the node.js CPU and other things will not be able to run while it's running.  So, all this does is time shift when it runs, it solves no other issues.  This is not what is usually meant by using async programming in node.js.  I'm not confused about anything.  I am trying to point out other aspects of this question/answer which you are trying to play terminology games to obscure.  Try this.  Try using `fs.readFileSync()` on a `setTimeout()` and see if that "async" code is good for your node.js server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know what each of those does and how it works, I just corrected your "it still runs synchronously and blocks" which is technically incorrect. I'm not obscuring anything, I'm just trying to make professionals use terminology properly. "Try using fs.readFileSync()" --- try using it on a single core CPU and see that the threads are preemptively scheduled and only one of them is running on the core at any given moment in time. It's surprising that you would not count that use "blocking" as well, since - well, it blocks does not it?

Comment: To summarise: why do you treat native kernel threads differently to execution contexts/queues managed by nodejs? Neither of them *guarantee* parallel execution.

Comment: `readFileSync()` is blocking for node.js no matter how many cores you have in your CPU so I'm not sure what that part of your comment meant.  A primary factor in node.js development is whether the single Javascript node.js thread is blocked or not.  That's the issue I'm speaking of here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105771/discussion-between-zerkms-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0):

You have never called the function.

```
function myAsyncFunction(num,cb){
   if(num>10){
      cb(true);
   }else{
      cb(false);
   }
}


myAsyncFunction(100, function(result){


   console.log('The result is = ' + result); //this never gets called

});
```